# Thumbnails in ACF Query Results

Tags: post-thumbnails, wp-list-pages

I'm using pagelist_ext to list all pages under a specific category: http://thenorthshorescene.com/bands/

The list was getting long, so I created some additional pages that add another level of filtering by querying ACF meta info, e.g., http://thenorthshorescene.com/rock/

This is all working fine, but ideally, the styling of the query pages would match the /bands/ page. I'm struggling to get the query to pull the featured images and excerpts for each page. Here's my query code:

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array( 
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'page',
    'orderby'       => 'name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'     => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query'    => array(
        'relation'      => 'OR',
    array(
        'key'       => 'genre',
        'value'     => 'country',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => 'genre2',
        'value'     => 'country',
        ),
    ),
));
    if( $posts ): ?>        
        <ul><?php foreach( $posts as $post ):   setup_postdata( $post ); ?>     <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>       </li><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Obviously, this code doesn't even include an attempt at pulling in this information -- what I've tried so far was

```
 <img src=<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>>
```

but it was tough to get this to behave correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) echos a complete HTML `<img>` tag, not just the URL of the image.  So, just use:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail ()?>
```

rather than

```
<img src='<?php the_post_thumbnail () ?>'>
```